# Uncheck CheckBox1 if one of multiple other Chechboxes are unchecked

Tags: excel, vba

I have `UserForm1` consisting of four `Checkboxes`:

`CheckBox1`  --> Main Checkbox 
`CheckBox2`  --> Sub Checkbox 
`CheckBox3`  --> Sub Checkbox 
`CheckBox4`  --> Sub Checkbox

Now if the user check/unchecks `CheckBox1` the `sub CheckBoxes 2-4` get automatically checked/unchecked using this VBA:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CheckBox2.Value = True
    CheckBox3.Value = True
    CheckBox4.Value = True
Else
    CheckBox2.Value = False
    CheckBox3.Value = False
    CheckBox4.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

Howerver, now I want to achieve that in case one of the `sub CheckBoxes 2-4` gets unchecked the `main checkbox` gets automatically unchecked as well without unchecking the other `sub CheckBoxes.`

**Example:** 
The user first clicks on `CheckBox1` and then the `Checkboxes 2-4` get automatically checked. 
Then the User uncheckes `Checkbox2` and the `CheckBox1` gets automatically unchecked whereas the `Checkbox 3-4` remain checked.

Something like this:

```
Sub Check_Uncheck()
If any of Checkbox 2-4 is unchecked then
only uncheck CheckBox1 but do not change any other sub CheckBox
End
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a `UserForm` scoped variable to let change events process or not their code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim blockChange As Boolean

Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    If Not blockChange Then
        blockChange = True
        If CheckBox1 Then
            CheckBox2.Value = True
            CheckBox3.Value = True
            CheckBox4.Value = True
        Else
            CheckBox2.Value = False
            CheckBox3.Value = False
            CheckBox4.Value = False
        End If
        blockChange = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    OnOff
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    OnOff
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
    OnOff
End Sub


Private Sub OnOff()
    If Not blockChange Then
        blockChange = True
        CheckBox1.Value = CheckBox2 And CheckBox3 And CheckBox4
        blockChange = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I needed.